# Pandas rolling window - Mark values

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe, I want to filter the rows where some column is stable within 10.0 units.

```
def abs_delta_fn(window):
   x = window[0]            
   for y in window[1:]:
      if abs(x-y) > 10.0:
         return False            
      return True

df['filter']= df['column'].rolling(5, min_periods=5).apply(abs_delta)
```

So, if a have a df like this

```
1   0
2   20
3   40
4   40
5   40
6   40
7   40
8   90
9   120
10  120
```

applying the rolling window I get:

```
1   0     nan
2   20    nan
3   40    nan
4   40    nan
5   40    False
6   40    False
7   40    True
8   90    False
9   120   False
10  120   False
```

How can I get this in a smart way?

```
1  0     nan (or False)
2  20    nan (or False)
3  40    True
4  40    True
5  40    True
6  40    True
7  40    True
8  90    False
9  120   False
10 120   False
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further your expected output?

Comment: There are 5 consecutive values that are equal or near equal.  These values are 40,40,40,40,40.   I want to filter the dataframe every time this occur for any value

Comment: I can use a for loop and do it, but i rather not...

Comment: @guilhermecgs I am not sure my answer solve your problem or not , but  seems like achieve what you need

Comment: give me 1 min to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you already know `rolling`, just adding `apply` after that , the key here is `.iloc[::-1]`, cause rolling is from the current row looking up(backward), but you need forward

```
s=df.x.iloc[::-1].rolling(5,min_periods=5).apply(lambda x : (abs((x-x[0]))<10).all())
df.loc[df.index.difference(sum([list(range(x, x+5))for x in s[s==1].index.values],[]))]

Out[1119]: 
      x
1     0
2    20
8    90
9   120
10  120
```

Comment: I think you got it...  It not a very efficient solution but I do not think there is one...